# perl variable perl variable

Tags: perl, variables

my code :

```
if ($funcarg =~ /^test (.*)/) {
  my $target1 = "http://$1/script/so.php";
    system("wget $target1");
```

so, when i type perl a.pl 127.0.0.1 the script must download http://127.0.0.1/script/so.php, but unfortunately it doesn't. where is my mistake?

```
 [root@localhost perl]# perl a.pl 127.0.0.1
http:///script/so.php: Invalid host name.
```

Comment: Please, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is `$funcarg`?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear how your command line argument gets from `@ARGV` to `$funcarg`. Or how it goes from `127.0.0.1` to (presumably) `test 127.0.0.1`. And I think that's where you're going wrong. I think that `$funcarg` doesn't contain what you think it does before you run the regex match.

This code does what I think you want. But I've had to make up two lines (as marked with a comment) and I'm pretty sure that your version of those two lines is where your misunderstanding is.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV or die "No argument given\n";

# I've made up the next two lines. But I think
# this is where your bug is.
my $host = $ARGV[0];
my $funcarg = "test $host";

if ($funcarg =~ /^test (.*)/) {
  my $target1 = "http://$1/script/so.php";
  print "$target1\n";
  system("wget $target1");
}
```